# Does my model in android need to be a singleton?

Tags: android, model

It seems to me that if you have some state or data in android that you want to access from different activities (but don't want to persist) you need a singleton. Is this correct or are there other ways to design an application?

It is not that I have a problem with singletons. I am just wondering because this is so radically different from normal desktop application development.

Answer (score 2):

What you said is definitely not correct and there are other ways to design an Android app.

Actually, for Android development, Singletons should be avoided or used sparingly and should **not** be used as the first or only solution. It should especially not be used to carelessly share data or state across Activities.

If you find your app requiring the use of Singletons for everything, then chances are... you're in need of a redesign for your app.

When using Singletons, there are actually a few things to keep in mind:

- They typically live throughout the entire lifecycle of the App until they're closed by the system closing your app
- Improperly created Singletons can easily leak memory
- Improperly designed Singletons and excessive use of Singletons can use up a lot of unneeded memory
- They're hard to use for testing

Overall, when using Singletons, you really need to think about if there's a sufficient need for that part of your app to be a Singleton.

For most situations, the answer is no. In the cases you mentioned, such as accessing state or data between Activities, it's a yes and no.

It's a yes because the need to access data might *warrant* the use of a Singleton. It's a no because the need to access the state of the app shouldn't.

Your use of the word 'state' is a quite unclear, but Activities should really be self-managed, since the state of an Activity shouldn't interfere with the state of another Activity. If it does, there are better ways to send that information to the Activity (*such as using Intent extras*) rather than creating a Singleton that is accessible for everything and existing for longer than it should.

There really is very few reasons to warrant a need for a Singleton.

In my experience, there are only two reasons that might allow for the use of a Singleton:

- The real need for a single instance to exist
- The Singleton is used very often and it's expensive to constantly create it, but there won't be any major side effects to keep it in memory.

For example, an SQLite Database is commonly used as a Singleton because a single synchronized instance of the database can help prevent more than one Activity or Service from reading/writing to the database. This helps prevent situations such as one object writing new data, while another object reads old data before the new data is written. Or the simple situation of two objects writing different data to the same field at the same time.

Additionally, an SQLite Database is also accessed very often by apps, so it doesn't make much sense to constantly open a database, fetch some data, close the database, open a database, write some data, close the database, and repeat.

I've seen developers use Singletons for a lot of situations, and most of them for really bad reasons.

The Good:

- Databases
- SharedPreferences (the app needs to access preferences way more often than normal)
- Logging system

The Bad:

- I saw a developer load up a large amount of Drawables and stored it in a Singleton upon starting his app... just so he could quickly use those drawables everywhere.
- I saw some developers using Singletons to hold a list of created Activities, so they could access those Activities methods and views... (*dead*)

I've seen more bad stories, but I can't recall them now.

Also, keep in mind that even though I said things like Databases are a good idea to be used as a Singleton, I only meant it has the needs to warrant the use of a Singleton. A database doesn't need to be a singleton and there are other solutions available that might fit your app better.

So always think about whether there's a need for you to use a Singleton.

In your case, does the state/data you need to access by other Activities really need to stay alive for the duration of the app and can it be solved through solutions like: SharedPreferences, Intent extras, Callback Interfaces, Databases, static classes/fields/methods, and etc.

If you've thought out your app well and really think a Singleton will benefit your app best, then use it. Don't forget to use an Application Context instead of the Activity's Context, because the Singleton will definitely outlive your Activity and you don't want memory leak issues.

Comment: My state/data is something like: a list of updates that I received from other users. Looking at your suggestions you say SharedPreferences, Databases but you also say that these are valid use cases for singletons.

This stuff comes from a service that is running in the background. The Service itself is basically also a singleton, because what is bindService but an asynchronous version of getInstance ...

I understand your aversion from singletons, this is in fact why I ask this question.

Comment: There's three things to address here. First, is your use case. If your list of updates (data from other users) is something used very often throughout your app and it makes no sense to constantly create and close that connection, then it makes sense to consider a Singleton. In a sense, this is why those who use a Repository pattern that fetches data from local databases, remote databases, and etc will often turn the Repository into a Singleton.

Comment: Second thing I wanted to address is that my answer was mostly targeting your statement that a Singleton is needed anytime 'state' or 'data' is accessed from multiple Activities. Using a Singleton for this is actually the improper approach due to the consequences that a Singleton can bring. Lots of times, there are other solutions available that better fit the way data or state is accessed by the Activities. So only use a Singleton if there is a sufficient reason to use a Singleton, which was what I wanted to address when you said 'a Singleton is needed whenever multiple Activities need access'

Comment: Third thing I wanted to address is that a Service actually isn't a Singleton. It's kind of similar to the difference between a Singleton and a Single Instance of a class. There's similarities, but they're different concepts. Binding a service is also different from a Singleton's getInstance() because binding a service to an Activity is simply creating a more tighter link between the Activity and Service, where unless you call `startService()` along with `bindService`, the Service will end when the bound Activity ends. A Service actually isn't meant to act like a Singleton either.

Comment: A Service is meant to be a way for your app to run operations outside of your Activity, especially the type of long operations that might extend past the life of your Activity, such as downloading updates, playing music, moving files, and etc. It's also typically not a good idea to keep Services alive longer than they're necessary, so except for a few types of Services, most Services will stop themselves after they finish performing their operations. A Service actually isn't a Singleton and they're actually very different. Singletons are actually more than just a single instance of an object.

Comment: You are correct about the Service, the lifecycle is indeed more subtle than that of a singleton. But I'm still wondering about the "other solutions" for sharing data within an app. So far I see: Intent Extras, Services (when started; but I guess this is more for 'performing actions' than for keeping data) and Singletons. Do you know any others? Also, do you often use Intent Extras? This mechanism seems so limited to me.

Comment: It really does depend on what type of data needs to be shared, since some data fits databases better, others fit preferences better, while others will even fit broadcasts better. There's a very large variety of ways to share data within the app. Besides Singletons, Databases, SharedPreferences, and Intent Extras, there are also options such as BroadcastReceivers (though this might count as Intent Extras, just a different way of delivery), static classes/fields, Content Providers, I/O files, Callback Interfaces, and more that escapes my memory right now.

Comment: Some solutions are more efficient for certain types of data, and certain ways to use that data might call for more specific solutions (such as Content Providers), and some solutions might require more security so access has to be more limited. As for Intent Extras, I do use it often when the situation calls for it. For example, when I need to send data to a foreground service, a lot of that data I need to send is shared best as an Intent extra. Honestly, Intent Extras are used quite often, since Intents is one of the primary ways that Apps communicate within itself and to other apps.